# How should I import the DBLP xml file into neo4j?

Tags: xml, neo4j, digital

I have the DBLP xml file. I am new to neo4j. I want to plot a network graph from the DBLP data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical graph structure defined within the dblp.xml file, so you have to define and extract your network first before you can work with. Hence, I'd guess there is no direct way to import the dblp.xml to neo4j. I do normally process the dblp.xml using custom Java scripts to convert it to a GEXF, based on the topology I wish to study.

More info on the content of the dblp.xml can be found here: http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/What+do+I+find+in+dblp.xml.html